# 400 Error when uploading file on server with auth token headers using Retrofit Android

Tags: java, retrofit, rx-java

```
public void uploadFile(String token, String org, String fileName){
    if(!ConnectionUtility.isNetworkAvailable2(getmContext())){
        return;
    }
    retryTrigger = false;


    File file = new File(fileName);
    String fName = file.getName();      

    RequestBody fb = RequestBody.create(file, MediaType.parse("application/pdf"));


    MultipartBody .Part body =
            MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("uploadFile", fName, fb );


    Map<String,String> headerMap = new HashMap<>();
    headerMap.put("User-Agent", "KMP");
    headerMap.put("X-Auth-Token", token);
    headerMap.put("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundarytkRt9rKilDJeeFe1");
    headerMap.put("accept", "application/json");
    headerMap.put("Csrf-Token", "nocheck");

 mCompositeDisposables.add(mKcpsLoginApiInterface.getFileUrl(org,headerMap,body)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .retry(1, throwable -> {
                retryTrigger = true;
                return false;
            })
            .subscribeWith(new DisposableSingleObserver<Response<GetFileUrl>>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(@NonNull Response<GetFileUrl> getFileUrlResponse) {                       
                    // Always get 400 error    
                    
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(@NonNull Throwable e) {

                }
            })
    );


}
```

My Interface looks like this

```
@Multipart
@POST("/o/{org}/files")
Single<Response<GetFileUrl>> getFileUrl(@Path("org") String org,
                                        @HeaderMap Map<String,String> headers,
                                        @Part MultipartBody.Part file
);
```

Additional Info:

- I've used the correct token and headers using swagger site and it works but when somehow I code it on my project, it won't work. Insights would be much appreciated.
- I always seem to get 400 error response code.
  Thank you

Comment: What URL are you invoking?

Comment: forgot to mention, I'm passing a local file from my phone 
fileName passed value looks like this

/data/user/0/com.projectName.project/cache/test.pdf